# Certbot unable to find AWS credentials when issuing certificate via dns for route53

Tags: ssl, dns, amazon-route53, lets-encrypt, certbot

I need to get an certificate for my domain hosted on AWS Route 53 from LetsEncrypt. I do not have any port 80 or 443 exposed since the server is used for VPN and does not have a public access.

So the only way to do this is via DNS validation of route 53.

So far I have installed certbot and dns-route53 plugin

```
sudo snap install --beta --classic certbot
sudo snap set certbot trust-plugin-with-root=ok
sudo snap install --beta certbot-dns-route53
sudo snap connect certbot:plugin certbot-dns-route53
```

I have created a special user in my AWS account who has access to Route53 and I have added the access key id and secret access key in the ~/.aws/config and also ~/.aws/credentials which looks something like this

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=foo
aws_secret_access_key=bar
```

Basically followed every step given here: https://certbot-dns-route53.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Now when I run the following command:

```
sudo certbot certonly -d mydomain.com --dns-route53
```

It gives the following output:

```
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator dns-route53, Installer None
Requesting a certificate for mydomain.com
Performing the following challenges:
dns-01 challenge for mydomain.com
Cleaning up challenges
Unable to locate credentials
To use certbot-dns-route53, configure credentials as described at https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html#best-practices-for-configuring-credentials and add the necessary permissions for Route53 access.
```

I went to the documentation given in the error message: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#best-practices-for-configuring-credentials

but I do not think there is anything wrong I am doing

I even went to the root level by doing `sudo su` and exported the AWS keys as env vars there and even exported the AWS keys in the home as well but it still throws me the same error.

Comment: Got the same issue, could you solve it?

Comment: No, unfortunately I could not find a solution to this

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Future questions about managing your servers can be asked on [sf].

Answer (score 5):

so I also ran into this same issue, and it's likely because of you running certbot with `sudo`, when do you do that, whatever user you've used as `~/`, is ignored, as instead, it's looking in `/root/`.

I fixed it by (centos) is my user where I have the `.aws/` directory with `config` and `credential` files.

```
sudo -s
ln -s /home/centos/.aws/ ~/.aws
```

```
ls -lsa ~/.aws
... /root/.aws -> /home/centos/.aws/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass creds as env var in the same command:

```bash
sudo AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_access_key AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your_secret_key certbot ...
```

This should work fine, too.